# ¿Que sucede cuando abro un FileReader/FileWriter?

Tags: java

tengo una duda la cúal trata básicamene sobre las clases `FileWriter` y `FileReader`. Cuando yo instancio estas clases entendí que se abre una conexión entre el archivo elegido y el programa java, ahora, porque tengo que cerrar esta conexión? ¿Qué sucede internamente?

¿Cómo trabaja el `BufferedReader` a diferencia de `FileReader` y `FileWriter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tu creas una conexión entre el fichero y el programa generas un Stream, estos Stream actúan como un canal entre el programa y el fichero, en ese canal se envía la información en bytes requerida. Entonces si no cierras puede que sigas usando los recursos de tu máquina que se usaron para ese stream, asi al cerar close(), liberas los recursos usados para el paso de informacion entre el canal.

`FileReader` y `FileWriter` son clases que se suelen usar para leer y escribir archivos de texto al usar 16 bits para el flujo de caracteres `BufferedReader` puede mejorar el rendimiento utilizando el bufer para la lectura de esos caracteres.

Desde la versión 7 de java ya no se usa close() en su lugar puedes capturar la excepción automáticamente con:

`try{}` y `cath(){}`

Comment: En todas las versiones de Java se utiliza `close`. Sucede que en Java 7 existe el `try-with-resources` donde el mismo bloque `try` puede cerrar los recursos que implementen la interfaz `Closeable` por ti, detrás de las escenas el método `close` se sigue llamando. Favor de editar esta parte para no confundir a los lectores.

Answer (score 3):

`BufferedReader` y `FileReader` son clases que extienden de la clase [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) y sirven para implementar el patrón de diseño [decorador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)). Este patrón se caracteriza por agregar funcionalidad de manera dinámica en tiempo de ejecución. Lo que tienes con la clase `java.io.Reader` es un contrato que establece cómo leer caracteres de un flujo de datos (stream). La clase `FileReader` va a leer caracteres de un archivo (cualquiera que fuese su formato). La clase `BufferedReader` decora a un `java.io.Reader` para facilitar la lectura de los caracteres que existe en ese lector al preconsumir su contenido y almacenarlo en un buffer, de manera que agiliza la lectura de los caracteres en el flujo de datos.

Para leer los caracteres de un archivo, basta con hacer esto:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("/ruta/del/archivo.ext");
```

Pero el `FileReader` no tiene ningún método adicional a los de `Reader`, por lo cual la lectura directa de esta clase sería de caracter por caracter o de un conjunto de caracteres almacenado en un arreglo (denotado por el método `FileReader#read(char[], int, int)`.

Para agilizar el rendimiento de la aplicación en estos casos, lo que se suele hacer es decorar la instancia de `FileReader` con una instancia de `BufferedReader`, de esta manera:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/ruta/del/archivo.ext"));
```

Ahora, siempre que se trabaja con un archivo físico, se abre una conexión a dicho archivo y se dice que la aplicación está utilizando el archivo. Al no cerrar esta conexión vía `Closeable#close` el sistema operativo marcará que la aplicación continúa utilizando el archivo, generando así un problema. Siempre se deben cerrar los recursos.

Tal como menciona @juliansalas, desde Java 7 puedes ahorrarte la llamada al método `close` al utilizar `try-with-resources`. Acá un ejemplo:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/ruta/del/archivo.ext"))) {
    //consume los datos del reader
    //...
} catch (IOException e) {
    //maneja tus excepciones, SIEMPRE
} /*
    no es necesario agregar un bloque finally para cerrar los recursos
    puesto que esta forma de utilizar try ya cerrará los recursos
    por ti y manejará el caso en que la variable `reader` no haya
    sido inicializada
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a un archivo el sistema operativo tiene que proveer [**descriptores de archivos**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptor_de_archivo) que son, en cierta medida, escasos.  Lo que ocurre cuando un program abre muchos archivos y no los cierra es que agota los descriptores que el sistema le provee a su proceso.

En programas pequeñitos que abren pocos archivos es posible no darse cuenta de esto, pero en programas más complicados o programas que corren por mucho tiempo (e.g., servidores), lo que ocurre en algún momento es que se agotan y el programa se queda sin poder abrir archivos nuevos.

> ¿Cómo trabaja el `BufferedReader` a diferencia de `FileReader` y `FileWriter`?

El `BufferedReader` es un [**decorador**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) que añade funcionalidad a un `Reader` de base.  El objetivo es que la manera más económica de leer de un archivo es en bloques, pero muchos programas prefieren leer un octeto o caracter a la vez.  El `BufferedReader` soluciona esto leyendo un bloque a la vez del `Reader` de base, guardándolos temporeramente, y sirviéndolos poco a poco a su consumidor.